# Adding elements from various elements into one container but won't be contained

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woothemes

I would like to re-organise the my singe-course page (comparable to single product of woocommerce i suppose). I chose to add a container with inline-flex layout (the light blue background) and create a section where i add content from various actions to. Now i managed to add the title and content to this parent section, but when i try to add the buttons, they appear outside of the section. Even though i was consistent in the action-adding procedure. Any (other) way to get the button into the section? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', 'add_attributes_to_header', 20 );



  function add_attributes_to_header(){
    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', open_container_div_section() ,7); 
//Opens the second container in the header bar(the one you see highlighted in the picture)

    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before',array( 'Sensei_Course', add_the_title_to_header()), 50 ); 
    //Adds 'deel 1 - hoofdstuk 1'

    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before',array( 'Sensei_Course', the_content()), 51); 
    //adds 'met een header3' and the other text below that

    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', add_the_button_to_header(), 52); 
    //calls seperate function to place the button, but fails to get it in the container

    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before',array( 'Sensei_Course', 'the_course_enrolment_actions'), 55);  
    //THIS also adds the button, but also puts it beside the container 

    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', close_container_div_section() ,75); 
    //Closes the section container in the header bar
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix it by containing a customly inserted do_action().

Within the created header i invoke:

```
add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', open_container_div_section() ,22);
```

and then :

```
do_action('add_elements_to_section');
```

and finally:

```
add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', close_container_div_section() ,75);
```

Then i add an action to this custom hook:

```
add_action('add_elements_to_section', 'add_them');  
function add_them(){
    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before',array( 'Sensei_Course', add_the_title_to_header()), 50 );
    add_action( 'voeg_elementen_toe_aan_section',array( 'Sensei_Course', 'the_course_enrolment_actions'), 21); 
}
```

Worked perfectly! All elements are now safely within the section container.